# Efficiently check rows that match certain values in Pandas DataFrame and add it to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (called: data) which has list of customers and their purchases - looks like this:

`ID     product
 1      orange
 1      banana
 2      apple
 2      orange
 2      banana
 3      banana
 3      apple
 4      apple
 5      apple
 5      orange
 5      banana`

what I would like to do is to generate a matrix where the indexes are the ids of the costumers and the columns to be the products and fill the matrix with either 1 if the costumer purchased the products or 0 if he didn't. the final matrix will look like this:

[image]

I have done it but it took too long as I'm dealing with around 20,000 costumers with more than 3,000 products (the estimated time to  be completed is around 4 days!).

Here is my code:

```
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index = customers, columns = products)
for indx in df_matrix.index:
    for col in df_matrix.columns:
        if ((data['ID'] == indx) & (data['product'] == col)).any() == True:
            df_matrix.loc[indx,col] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.get_dummies` my friend

have a look here
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: followed by `.groupby('ID').any()`

Comment: @noobie  thanks but I it the numbers of rows is equal to the number of rows in the first data frame not the number of customers.

Comment: is `ID` the index of the DataFrame?